# Is it possible to open *.dmp file and find out what cause ArcMap to crash?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.2, python-addin

Is it possible to find out what cause ArcMap to crash from *.dmp file? This files are located here:

> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\ESRI\ErrorReports

I have made some Python add-in to ArcMap wich sometimes works and sometimes ArcMap crases. But I can't find out what part of my add-in causes this event. Is it possible to open *.dmp file and find something there? Or is there any other option how debug already compiled ESRI add-in?

Comment: You probably wont get much out of the .DMP, if anything to help your narrow the problem down. If you could describe the steps you took which cause the crash to happen, we can evaluate it at Esri. Alternatively, please make sure to push submit on the error reports. They're actively reviewed.

Comment: I was hoping that I could retrieve some information from .DMP file.. The crash of ArcMap is not exact. Mostly the add-in works good (like 5:1), but if crash occurs, it's sometimes at the beginning of add-in workflow, sometimes in the middle and sometimes at the end (add-in runs for ca. 7 sec). So I am totaly out of idea how to find out why that happend.

Comment: The email address in your profile, did you attach that to the submission? If so, I can search for it here.

Comment: No, but I can reproduce the error and attach emai > Done :) Would you be so kind ! I could make aviable add-in file or python script.

Comment: I cant find anything from you in our system. You can email me the report, but I can't help you debug. I can only tell you if its a known/fixed issue, or the particular crash you're reporting is new to us. (khibma [at] esri.com)

Comment: Okey, thank you very much anyway. I will email you DMP file tomorrow, now I'm not at work. Anything could help me.